# Lightswitch Possible ? Multiple Choice Auto-Complete-Box in "Create New Data"- Screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Like in the title.
Is there a "decent" way to modify a "Auto-Complete-Box" to get multiple choices in it? 
Not only different options to select, but more than one item at once.

I am searching the web for a while now, hopefully i didnt miss something. If thats the case, it would be awesome if someone could link it.

Edit:

imgur.com/8IKniYd there you see, the screen. I got an auto-complete-box for item1 and 2. Item1 are the "main" items and I want to create relations between item1 and "many" items in item2. At the moment I only can create 1 relation at once, but this is kinda heavy to do. 1 Item1 can have about 15 Item2 "relations" So i need to fix this first.

Sry for my late response, was sick for the last days.

Greetings
Declade

Comment: Have you had a look at all of the jQuery Mobile controls?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the following links :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/18ddf7/filling-autocompletebox-with-values-in-lightswitch-2012/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/18ddf7/setting-value-in-autocompletebox-using-code-in-lightswitch-2/

If not, they could be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Yeah i kinda ran over them a few days ago, but I think I failed to explain my problem correctly. http://imgur.com/8IKniYd    there you see, the screen. I got an auto-complete-box for item1 and 2. Item 1 are the "main" items and i want to create relations between item1 and all the other items in item2. At the moment I only can create 1 relation at once, but this is kinda heavy to do. 1 Item1 can have about 15 Item2 "relations" So i need to fix this first.